# Should I prepare all queries even if they will only be executed once?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Using PHP's PDO class, does preparing queries cause a (slight even) performance hit that isn't made up if you only execute the query once per connection?  I'm making a small data access layer and I'm wondering if it's okay to blindly prepare all queries, or if I should only prepare queries that will be reused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prepared statements arent only for reused queries. They should be used for all queries that have untrusted data, making sure to bind the untrusted data. This eliminates SQL injection opportunities.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: It's fine to blindly prepare queries w/o any parameters?  Does it cause a performance hit (even a negligible one)?

Comment: Yes there will be a very small performance hit.  When you prepare a query it is sent to the server for parsing, then when you execute the query it is sent again. As opposed to just issuing query() and it only being sent once.

Comment: If you're worried about performance you can also set PDO to emulate prepared statements and thereby making only one trip to the server

Comment: @sreimer: which is the default setting (see this thread on the [internals list](http://marc.info/?t=130417648000003&r=1&w=2)).  Doing so also eliminates the protection from SQL Injection that's given by doing true prepared statements...

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't make sense. Use $dbh->quote & $dbh->query, its as secure and much faster.